# DAO Hibernate Java Select All rows into a collection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, dao

So, basically I have been stuck in the same process for like 1 week and I think I'm basically losing it. I have been doing and assignment where I cant change whats already being built but I need to use whats there to get my result.

What I want to do is select all rows from a table instead of just getting one with a key. I am using hibernate and DAO for it. I have the select just 1 query up and running now but I am facing with taking all the records and save them as a List or Collection.

```
public CachedObject get(String key) {
    CachedObject rtnValue = null;

    log.debug("Entering get(key) for key = " + key + "...");

    // try to find entry from db as long as key
    // is not in the do not cache list
    if (!getDoNotCacheKeys().contains(key)) {
        try {
            rtnValue = getDao().find( getFetchQueryName(), KEY_PARM_NAME, key);
            // if we got an object back - and it has not expired - reset
            // its last active timestamp value to now and save
            if (rtnValue != null && !rtnValue.hasExpired(getMaxIdle(), getMaxAge())) {
                log.debug("Cache entry being updated with current timestamp...");
                rtnValue.setLastActive(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                getDao().saveOrUpdate(rtnValue);
            }
        }
        catch (DatabaseException exc) {
            log.error("Exception triggered on get of cache entry with key = " + key, exc);
            if (exc.isSerializationException()) {
                try {
                    log.warn("Serialization of old value triggered exception - proceeding to remove obsolete record for key = " + key + "...");
                    int numRows = getDao().delete(getDeleteQueryName(), KEY_PARM_NAME, key);
                    log.info("The delete for key = " + key + " successfully deleted " + numRows + " rows in the db...");
                }
                catch (DatabaseException exc2) {
                    log.error("Unable to remove record for key " + key + " from the cache db...", exc2);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    else {
        log.info("Key " + key + " found in do not cache list - no lookup performed...");
    }
    log.debug("Exiting get(key) for key = " + key + "...");

    return rtnValue;
}
```

Which is then used to add it to the cache

```
public CachedObject add(String key, CachedObject obj) {
    CachedObject rtnValue = obj;

    log.debug("Entering add(key, obj) for key = " + key + "...");

    // add to the cache as long as the key value is 
    // not in the do not cache list
    if (!getDoNotCacheKeys().contains(key)) {
        // update timestamp values
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        obj.setLastActive(new Timestamp(now));
        obj.setFirstActive(new Timestamp(now));

        // persist obj to cache
        try {
            log.debug("Saving cache object to the db...");
            getDao().saveOrUpdate(obj);
        }
        // if object with same key is already in db - then it must
        // have been added after check or has expired - so just perform get to
        // read it in 
        catch (ConstraintViolationException exc) {
            log.warn("Existing cache object with key = " + key + " found in the database. Attempting to update existing copy via get()...");
            CachedObject dbCopy = get(key);
            if (dbCopy == null) {
                log.error("Unexpected null returned on get of existing cache entry with key = " + key + " !!!");                    
            }
            // now replace serialized data just in case the class
            // has changed and won't deserialize properly
            // also copy over last and first active timestamps
            // since 
            dbCopy.setCacheObject(obj.getCacheObject());
            dbCopy.setLastActive(obj.getLastActive());
            dbCopy.setFirstActive(obj.getFirstActive());
            try {
                getDao().saveOrUpdate(dbCopy);
            }
            catch (DatabaseException exc2) {
                log.error("Unexpected error triggered while updating existing cached object with new serialized content...", exc2);
            }
            // set return to return the db based copy and not the original
            // passed into this method
            rtnValue = dbCopy;

        }
        catch (DatabaseException exc) {
            log.error("Exception triggered on save of cache entry with key = " + key + ": " + obj, exc );
        }            
    }
    else {
        log.info("Key " + key + " found in do not cache list - no add performed...");
    }

    log.debug("Exiting add(key, obj) for key = " + key + "...");

    return rtnValue;
}
```

What I want to do now, is try to select all of the records now and save them in a collection so I can use them later on with a validation (still needed to do), but as a matter of fact I dont quite get how to use DAO to select all of the records.

The find() method is really simple

```
CachedObject find(String queryName, String keyParmName, Object key) throws DatabaseException;
```

I was thinking of something like

```
ArrayList<CachedObject> listObj = getDao().find(fetchAllQueryName, null, getDao());
```

But, changing the find() to return something like a collection. I do not know, Im quite desesperate at this point.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks and Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dandalf is right you have to create a method something like

`getDao().getAll()`

or

`getDao().findAll()`
 as you mentioned in comment that this method is not inherited from AbstractDao , then obviously you have you keep signature in `AbstractDao` as a abstract method, as functionality increases different methods are introduced, you cannot do everything by just predefined methods.

Comment: that seems to be the right approach, what I dont know is if I should create in each that it is inherited. For instance for find,there are these 2...
CachedObject find(String queryName, String keyParmName, Object key) throws DatabaseException;---
public CachedObject find(String queryName, String keyParmName, Object key) throws DatabaseException {
        return (CachedObject) myDao.find(queryName, new String[] {keyParmName}, 
                new Object[] {key});
    }

Comment: Shall I create it identical for this but for findAll, obviously returning a collection (or List) because it is supposed to be like that.

Comment: yes you are right, create a abstract method in your AbstractDao and all inheriting classes will inherit them, and if your one class needs functionality for now them implement that functionality and your other class donot need it now then just give it simple body `{}` returning null, but at one point you will need that functionality in other class too because thats why generic Abstract classes are meant to be made :)

Comment: Yes, I know the concept but first time using hibernate and DAO, so lost on some definitions. But guess if its working like that for find, should replicate it for findAll but using a Collection as a return. Just one last question, shall I use a collection or an ArrayList, considering objects from DAO?

Comment: actually I dont have authenticated resource to answer that question but what i used to do it i keep returnType a parent class like `List` and return child classes `Arraylist`